# Getting "Authentication credentials were not provided." error when making a request to another api endpoint with required auth, on behalf of a user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

    username = serializer.validated_data['username']
    password = serializer.validated_data['password']

    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    login(request, user)

    session_id = request.session.session_key
    csrf_token = get_token(request)

    request_headers = {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
        'Cookie': f"sessionid={session_id}",
    }


    # Url to request mail for email confirmation
    url_path = reverse('send-mail-confirm-email')
    full_url = request.scheme + '://' + request.get_host() + url_path
      
    requests.get(
        full_url,
        headers=request_headers,
    )

    return Response(
            serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers
        )
```

Getting "Authentication credentials were not provided." error when making a request to another api endpoint with required authentication, on behalf of a user. I have included cookie with sessionid, and csrf_token in the request headers. It doesn't work either way.

Comment: Anyone? Everything should work...

Comment: With token based auth it works.